# Change price calculation in PrestaShop

Tags: php, symfony, content-management-system, prestashop

I search a method to change the price calculation in PrestaShop.
My customer sells all kinds of hardware like screws, bolts, nuts etc.

He use a software aside PrestaShop to manage his products, customers, orders etc.
The difficulty is that a product has price per 100 items for example but the product is sell only in box of 200.

I display price like this : 10$ for 100 items
But the quantity must be a multiple of the packaging. Here 200, 400, 600 etc. (I tried to change the "step" attribute in the html input but it doesnt work).

And after that, if a customer buy 400 items, the price should be 40$ (100 items * 4 that is 10$ * 4).
By default PrestaShop give 4000$ (400 * 10$ !) and it's totally logical.

My question is, how do I change the price calculation to get to what i want ?
In which part of the code can I find what interests me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it is not a problem about code. You are not selling items else boxes with items. You must set stock according that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

I sell products packaged in different quantities (unit, box of 100, box of 200 etc) and the price can be for 100 pieces, individually etc.

For each product I have the following information transmitted by the management software: price unit, price coefficient, conditioning unit and conditioning coefficient.

I think I have all the data to do the calculations I need but I'm not sure which part of the code I can find what handles the price calculation.

Comment: Price calculation is handled by Product::getPriceStatic / Product::getPriceCalculation  methods.  Anyway you could try to achieve your result with discount per quantity native feature ?

Comment: You can create a new product which is a pack of 100 pieces.

Comment: @user3256843 thank you for your answer I check this in a few moment.

Comment: @Nikita I tried this but it doesn't work as I want.

Comment: can you share your backoffice?

Comment: @user3256843 thank you I find what I want in Product::getPriceStatic / Product::getPriceCalculation methods.